# Can I fill database attributes without using rails console

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, authentication

I am creating a CMS app which has authentication.
Can I add an initial user to the database automatically without using the console?

So the client will take the CMS with its initial username and password, so he can access its admin area and then it changes it.

Comment: Im guessing from this you wont have access to the server the app is hosted on.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The best way is similar to what others have said:

`rake db:seed`

With the necessary script in your seeds file.

I assume the client will need to setup the database in the rails fashion. You could just get them to run that after `rake db:create db:migrate` etc.

You could also use `rake db:setup` which runs `create`, `migrate` and `seed`.

Alternatively:

Build a very simple form that shows on the index if there aren't any users in the system. This form allows the user to create their own username/password. Depending on your requirements, this might be a better option.

Answer (score 1):

Best way is to use database seed for initializing data in database.
You can add users in db/seed.rb file and run

```
rake db:seed
```

from command line.
For more details see

- http://edgeguides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_migrations.html#migrations-and-seed-data
- http://www.xyzpub.com/en/ruby-on-rails/3.2/seed_rb.html

Comment: Is there anyway to do it using models??

Comment: @amronrails Yes. You can use any model of your rails application for populating data.This might be helpful, a sample seed file for seeding users and roles [link](https://github.com/stormfire/railsApps/blob/master/db/seeds.rb)

Answer (score 0):

[yaml_db](https://github.com/yamldb/yaml_db) is another option to consider

Unline *rake db:seed* which requires you to write ruby code yourself, it allows you do save all of the data you have in the database and then re-populate it again with only 2 commands.

```
rake db:data:dump   ->   Dump contents of Rails database to db/data.yml
rake db:data:load   ->   Load contents of db/data.yml into the database
```